# Why is couchdb login good but couchdb session empty, using vuejs and pouchdb

Tags: vue.js, authentication, couchdb, pouchdb

Using Vusjs, pouchdb-browser, CouchDB, pouchdb-authentication

I want to check if a session is open to use for offline stay logged in.

When I login with db.logIn from pouchdb-authentication:

response:  `{ok: true, name: "01HAYJ", roles: Array(1)}`

When I run "getSession" i get userCtx.name as null

session response:

```
info:
authentication_handlers: Array(2)
0: "cookie"
1: "default"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
ok: true
userCtx:
name: null
roles: Array(0)
```

Here is a snippet of my action:

```
setUser({commit, dispatch},payload){
      console.log('store action payload: ', payload);
      var user = payload.user;
      var pass = payload.pass
      
      db.logIn(user, pass , function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
          if (err.name === 'unauthorized' || err.name === 'forbidden') {
            alert("Login failed, check user or password!")
          } else {
          
          }
        }
      }).then(function (response) {
        // handle response
        console.log('response: ', response);
        db.getSession(function (err, response) {
          if (err) {
            // network error
            console.log('session error: ', error);
            
          } else if (!response.userCtx.name) {
            // nobody's logged in
            console.log('nobody is logged in' );
            
          } else {
            // response.userCtx.name is the current user
            console.log('response.userCtx.name: ', response.userCtx.name );
            commit('setUser', response.userCtx.name)
            router.push({ name: 'dashboard'})
          }
        });
        commit('setUser', payload.user)
      }).catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log('error: ', error);
        dispatch('logOut');
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a mix of callbacks and promises in your code. It is possible that db.login is not completing before the db.session call. I am not sure from the snippet if the "then" is part of another Promise, but here is how I would structure the call:

```
setUser({commit, dispatch},payload){
      console.log('store action payload: ', payload);
      var user = payload.user;
      var pass = payload.pass
      
      db.logIn(user, pass).then(function (response) {
        // handle response
        console.log('response: ', response);
        return db.getSession();
      }).then(response) {
        //check user details from the session response here
        commit('setUser', payload.user)
      }).catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log('error: ', error);
        dispatch('logOut');
      });
    }
```

(this is an example - there may be typos!)